# Keep "no data" tiles with r.reclass rules

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, reclassify

Working in QGIS 2.14.0-Wien.

I want to reclassify a raster with the r.reclass GRASS 7 tool, but want to keep the "no data" tiles as "no data".

I understand that I need to create a text "rules" file to inform r.reclass of what classes to create with lines such as "XXXX thru XXX = 1", but am not sure of the syntax to preserve the "no data" tiles.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GRASS Manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.reclass.html):

Categories to become no data are specified by setting the output category value to "NULL".

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps another way is to set all your values to a text like you mentioned and then for the values you want to keep same (no data) you can use *. e.g:

```
1 thru 5 = 2
3 thru 8 = 10
* = *
```